# What is the portable way to know the maximum and minimum nice value?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, pid

I am trying to set the priority of my processes using the functions `setpriority` and `nice`, but I want to know what is the maximum and the minimum value that I can use. Reading the `man setpriority`, it says that can be [-20,20], [-20,19] or other value. I am currently using [-1000, 1000] because it truncates to the limit value. But in some OS, according to `man setpriority` can be [-infinity, 15].

I tried to use the `getrlimit` function, but returned 0 for `rlim_cur` e `rlim_max`, what is not true.

If helps:
I am using Ubuntu 14.04.
Compiling with the flag `-sdt=c90` (ANSI C).
And defining: `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500`

Comment: From `man getrlimit`: "***RLIMIT_NICE** [...] The actual ceiling for the nice value is calculated as 20 - rlim_cur.*".